# Normal Knight sees the Big Picture during his Countrywide Travels

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, chess

Normal Knight is savvy, energy saving as he travels through Regular Country... Ride along and Document Details of his Journey

As this Knight (only chess move allowed) journeys through ,
he takes minimum (63) of hops to reach his destination of 64 starting from 1. He makes a pit stop at every successively numbered site. No cell is ever revisited.

He is very helpful Knight. Unlike Prime  Knight, he is willing to give you more details of his journey. The numbered cells shown in the picture are mandatory stops.

Just like him, you always should see big picture and figure out the rest of the steps of his economical journey.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magical Knight Moves with Effortless Ease in his Magical Kingdom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85182/magical-knight-moves-with-effortless-ease-in-his-magical-kingdom) - the linked puzzle is essentially a repost of this one with more information (the red numbers) which enables it to be solved more easily.

Answer (score 3):

### Step-by-step deductions (partial)

- > From any corner there are only two possible knight's moves. So **G6=12** and **B6=53** and F2,G3 must be 17,19 in some order.
- > From D1 (50) we can't move to E3 (15) or F2 (17,19), so B2,C3 must be 49,51 in some order.
  >  Then from A2 (30) we can't move to C3 (49,51), so C1,B4 must be 29,31 in some order.
- > The only options for 2 are C2,B3. So 4 can't be in B3, and (since B4 is 29,31) 4 can't be in C6 either. So **C4=4**.
- > From A4 we can only reach B6 (53), C5 (25), or B2,C3 (49,51). So **A4=52**.
- > From H2 (35) we can only reach F1,F3,G4. So two of these three must be 34,36. Also 16 is between E3 (15) and one of F2,G3 (17,19), so it must be in one of F1,G4. So F1,F3,G4 are 16,34,36 in some order.
- > From B1 we can only reach C3 (49,51) or D2,C3 (one of which must be 3). So **B1=48**, which means **C3=49** and **B2=51** and D2,A3 are 3,47 in some order.
- > From B3 we can only reach A1 (1), A5 (5), C1 (29,31), C5 (25), D2 (3,47), or D4 (45). So this square must be one of 2,46.
- > From F1 we can only reach D2 (3,47), E3 (15), G3 (17,19), or H2 (35). So in the end this square can't be 34 or 36: we have **F1=16**, hence **G3=17** and **F2=19**.

### Filled grid (partial)

> [image]

(A big number means that number is definitely in that square. Two or three small numbers means that square *must* contain one of those numbers: e.g. G1 must be either 33 or 63, although either 33 or 63 might also be elsewhere. A number with a question mark means that square is one of only a few possibilities for that number: e.g. 13 must be in F4 or E7, although either of those squares might also be another number.)

Here I can't see any more immediate deductions to make, so I'm going to try a "what-if".

Comment: Couldn't 63 be in F4 or G5 as well?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire F2 as well

Comment: As I see it, G1,F2, F4, G5 are all possibilities

Comment: If you look at big picture, you have lot more clues than you think

Comment: Anyway, Magical Knight will be coming tomorrow morning to dispense his wisdom for efficient navigation and even more clues

Comment: @SteveV Not F2 as that square must be taken by either 17 or 19 to obtain 18 on H1.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes, of course. My notation "33,63" in a square means that that square *must* be either 33 or 63, not that 33 and 63 must be either there or somewhere else. I thought that would be clear, since the other makes no sense in the big picture, but I'll edit.